# What's the '@' do in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

What's the '@' do in ActionScript? Can't find info on this anywhere, primarily because Google and other search engines strip out special characters from search queries.

Comment: A code example for context would be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the **attribute identifier**. Documentation can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#attribute_identifier).

Answer (score 3):

It's also used for [two-way binding](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Two-way+Data+Binding) in Flex4 and [embedding](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html) assets